# External style not picked by div element

Tags: html, css, external, stylesheet

I am relatively new to CSS so please let me know if there is a silly mistake on below. While trying out one of the examples on **w3cschools** I used the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Demonstrating the Box Model</h2>

<p>The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around every HTML element. It consists of: borders, padding, margins, and the actual content.</p>

<div>This text is the actual content of the box. We have added a 25px padding, 25px margin and a 25px green border. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and result was correct with a green border and text in grey background.

However while trying to do the same with an external css like below.

This code is in thumbnailTest.css

```
.dics{

    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;

}
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="C:\Users\Sam\Documents\workspace\test_project\cssTest\thumbnailTest.css">


</head>
<body>

    <div class="dics">This text is the actual content of the box. We have added a
        25px padding, 25px margin and a 25px green border. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The same output is not replicated it appear as plain text and no styling.

**Although path to the css is correct also I have tried putting relative path it is not working**

There is no issue with the css inclusion as it works for many other styles I have used but with Div it is not working

Here is the required workspace image

[image]

Comment: I think it is because of the href. You probably put wrong link.

Comment: Most probably your path to the css file is not correct.

Comment: You don't put href= link like that . It should reference to where you current html file is.

Comment: @HermLuna alreadyy tried with relative path also this is not working

Comment: @MuhammadUsman  already tried with relative path also this is not working :(

Comment: your css files is there where your html files is?

Comment: @SanyamGoel show us an image of your project folder.

Comment: Different folders @Leothelion but same way I have already included in so many HTML's and it works. Only for div element I see this is not working

Comment: try this : C://Users/Sam/Documents/workspace/test_project/cssTest/thumbnailText.css

Comment: @chirag did not work seems some other sort of a problem

Comment: @SanyamGoel this issue is only related to path. Put css files where your index file is or inspect element and check that css is adding on that page or not and you will get your answer.

Comment: The link should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../cssTest/thumbnailTest.css">`

Comment: ../cssTest/thumbnailTest.css try this url.

Comment: You have wrong spelling in thumbnailText.css to thumbnailTest.css  ... x to s

Comment: @cjmling nice catch..it might be issue.

Comment: yup spelling mistake

Comment: I copied the name and tested and it is still not working

Comment: @cjmling I corrected the name but that did not work either

Comment: 1. may be inspect element and see network or console tab that the css file is actually got loaded.  2. Make sure ur .dics css is actually in thumbnailTest.css 3. For good practise you should always use relative path. 4. Make sure there is no other spelling mistake the version shown here is same as what you actually got.

Comment: @cjmling yes thank you so much now it is fixes also there was an issue in the ref syntax. it is working now. Thank you all  :)

Comment: @cjmling Please add to answers I will upvote and accept it

Comment: @SanyamGoel done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was spelling mistake in referencing the css file. 
 `thumbnailTest.css => thumbnailText.css`

OP already edited based on the comment and solved his problem.

Answer (score 0):

REplace css link with this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../cssTest/thumbnailTest.css">
```

Comment: Already using the external sheets with absolute path and is working fine every where.

Comment: Use this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="cssTest/thumbnailText.css"> if your index.html file is located in "test_project" folder and your CSS file is into "cssTest" folder.